# SQL if i dont give a value it will insert as null.if it has a value it will be inserted onto the database

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning i want to know how can i insert a null value when the user do not dont give a value in the field but when the user give a value it wil insert onto my database

```
<?php
require "connect.php";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    // echo var_dump($data);
    $response = array();
 
    $vesselid = $data['vesselid'];
 

This the datatype of my values anchor and berth are timestamp
this are the values that i want to insert null or not

     $anchor_eta = $data['anchor_eta'];
        $anchor_ata = $data['anchor_ata'];
        $anchor_etd = $data['anchor_etd'];
        $anchor_atd = $data['anchor_atd'];
        $berth_eta = $data['berth_eta'];
        $berth_ata = $data['berth_ata'];
        $berth_etd = $data['berth_etd'];
        $berth_atd = $data['berth_atd'];

   //up to here
```

checking for my vessel id if my vessel id already exist

```
  $check = "SELECT * FROM vessel_transaction WHERE vesselid='$vesselid'";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$check));

    if(isset($result)){
        $response['value'] = 2;
        $response['message'] = "Record Already Exist";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

   else{
```

this is my insert query

```
 $insert = "INSERT INTO vessel_transaction(vesselid,anchor_eta,anchor_ata,anchor_etd,anchor_atd,berth_eta,berth_ata,berth_etd,berth_atd) VALUE ('$anchor_eta','$anchor_ata','$anchor_etd','$anchor_atd','$berth_eta','$berth_ata','$berth_etd','$berth_atd')";
    // echo json_encode($insert);
    if (mysqli_query($con,$insert)) {
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        // echo $last_id;
        $queryResult = $con->query("SELECT transaction_id from vessel_transaction where id = $last_id");
            $result = array ();
            while($fetchData = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
                $result = $fetchData;
            }
        $response['value'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = $result;
        echo json_encode($response);   
    }
    else{
        $response['value'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Failed to Add";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

   }
    

   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

First, make sure that `variables` which *optional* inserted to have a `default` values.

For instance,

#### Code Section

***PHP CODE SECTION***

```
// String variables
$stringVar = "default value"

//Numerical variables
$numVar = 0

//Boolean Variables
$bool = FALSE //or true depending on your condition
// others
$others = NULL
```

***SQL CODE SECTION***

Every time the user leaves this field, there's a default value that will be appended into the database without having any tribble.

**But**, Make sure your *database variables constraints* isn't indicate `NOT NULL`

For Instance,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
    Id INT NOT NULL, -- This variable must have value.
    name VARCHAR(30),
    phone INT -- This variable isn't mandatory to have a value.
);
```

Comment: cause i had a datepicker so if the user does not pick a date and time the database must display an null if ever the user did noy select a value

Comment: It depends on your program structure. If you're allowing the user to choose a default value which is `NULL` means that the user has the choice not to choose from the select bar, you have to leave your variable constraint without `NOT NULL` in the database structure. Besides, the select bar variable has to be initialized by `NULL`. So, if the user decided to leave it without selecting anything. It will be stored as a `NULL` value. Now, there's another question had to be asked. Is `Date` type into the sql database allows me to store `NULL` value? The answer is YES!.

Comment: But, if you want your user to mandatory select a value, you've to add `NOT NULL` to ur variable when you create the database. For instance, i want to make this variable restricted inserted, it has to be like that `dateVar date NOT NULL`. Besides, make sure you have a validation activated for your `datepicker` select label, so the user has to select a variable from.